# ¿Cómo comparar 1 tabla con las mismas columnas SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen Dia colegas

Soy nuevo en SQL Y Quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de hacer lo siguiente mediante un stored procedure:

[image]

El problema surge cuando quiero hacer una consulta desde esta tabla :

[image]

Como podrán notar la tabla `Balanza` solo tiene Una columna llamada `Fecha` y yo lo que quiero es lograr Comparar Fechas mediante `Clasificacion` entre `2018-06-01 00:00:00.000` y `2019-03-01 00:00:00.000` cabe recalcar que el valor de las `fechas` es dinámico y y el valor de `clasificacion` también

Ya e intentado hacerlo pero sin exito :

```
     (SELECT
    Cuenta, Clasificación as Clasificación1,Fecha as Fecha1
    FROM BalanzasNuevoFormato WHERE Fecha = '2018-06-01 00:00:00.000')
 UNION
 (SELECT
    Cuenta, Clasificación as Clasificacion2,Fecha as Fecha2
    FROM #TempBalanzasNuevoFormato WHERE Fecha = '2019-05-01 00:00:00.000')
ORDER BY Cuenta;
```

[image]

Si existe alguna forma de hacerlo estaría eternamente agradecido , ya que llevo días y no puedo pasar de esto ,Gracias de antemano.

El resultado que necesito es el siguiente ,algo por el estilo que al ejecutar el store procedure solo pase la fecha como parámetros y por consecuencia me traiga esa tabla con los datos de las fechas:

[image]

> Actualizacion ,Funciona la respuesta de  @elierickdevelopment  pero no aplica correctamente un `Where`

Ejemplo `where Cuenta like '000%'` como se puede apreciar si cumple el where pero me trae los demas valores en 0
[image]

Comment: ¿ Cual es el resultado que necesitas ? intenta ilustrarlo en una imagen

Comment: Actualice la pregunta mi estimado , espero ser claro con el problema cualquier duda quedo a disposición ,saludos

Comment: La verdad que no se te entiende lo que quieres decir, asi que tomate un tiempo y redacta la pregunta lo mejor que puedas, recuerda q fisicamente estamos muy lejos y debes ser lo mas claro posible

Comment: lo que necesitas es un comparativo, sumar los montos por clasificación y fechas  o bien por mes

Comment: Los datos que muestras no corresponden entre sí. Es complicado entender lo que deseas si los datos de muestra y los resultados no coinciden. También es importante incluir los datos y código como texto y no como imagen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes mejorar la pregunta como te sugieren en los comentarios. de todas maneras, he tratado de replicar tu escenario con variables tipo tablas. En este ejemplo la idea es obtener la suma de los montos por fecha y clasificación, pero también se puede modificar para obtener el resumen por mes si así lo deseas.

Primero obtengo las clasificaciones que tienen registros en dichas fechas (las que seleccionará el usuario supongo), y las agrego a la variable tipo tabla @RESUMEN, posterior recorro las clasificaciones y agrego las sumas de los montos según las fechas y clasificación correspondiente.

```
DECLARE @TABLA AS TABLE (id int identity, Cuenta VARCHAR(50), Nombre VARCHAR(100), Monto float , Fecha DateTime, Clasificacion Varchar(100))
    INSERT INTO @TABLA (Cuenta, Nombre, Monto, Fecha, Clasificacion)
    VALUES ('201-0000','ACREEDORES DIVERSOS','1206047.85','01/06/2018','Acreedores Diversos'),
    ('201-0000','ACREEDORES DIVERSOS','25633.85','01/05/2019','Acreedores Diversos'),
    ('201-0000','BANCO ACTINVER','9919.29','01/06/2018','Acreedores Diversos Sub'),
    ('201-0201','BREVO SEMINUEVOS','0','01/06/2018','Acreedores Diversos Sub'),
    ('201-0201','Nombre 1','8500.35','01/05/2019','ACTIVO'),
    ('201-0201','Nombre 2','10500.45','01/05/2019','PTU'),
    ('201-0201','Nombre 3','10500.45','01/03/2019','Otros Ingresos')
    
    DECLARE @RESUMEN AS TABLE (id int identity, Clasificacion varchar(100), TotalFecha1 float, TotalFecha2 float)
    
    DECLARE @Fecha1 varchar(10) = '01/06/2018', @Fecha2 varchar(10) = '01/05/2019',
    @Cont int =1,  @Cant int =0 , @Clasificacion varchar(100);
    
        INSERT INTO @RESUMEN (Clasificacion,TotalFecha1,TotalFecha2)
SELECT DISTINCT Clasificacion,0,0 FROM @TABLA WHERE Fecha =@Fecha1 AND Cuenta LIKE '%000' OR Fecha = @Fecha2 AND Cuenta LIKE '%000'
    
    SET @Cant = (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM @RESUMEN)
    
    WHILE (@Cont <= @Cant)
    BEGIN
    
        SELECT @Clasificacion = Clasificacion FROM @RESUMEN WHERE id = @Cont
    
        UPDATE @RESUMEN SET TotalFecha1 = ISNULL((Select SUM(Monto) FROM @TABLA where Fecha = @Fecha1 AND Clasificacion = @Clasificacion),0), 
                            TotalFecha2 = ISNULL((Select SUM(Monto) FROM @TABLA where Fecha = @Fecha2 AND Clasificacion = @Clasificacion),0)
        WHERE Clasificacion = @Clasificacion 
    
    SET @Cont = @Cont + 1
    END
    
    SELECT * FROM @TABLA
    SELECT * FROM @RESUMEN
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias llevaba tanto en este problema , acople tu comentario a mi query y funciono perfectamente

Comment: oye una duda en que parte del codigo podria poner una condicionante por ejemplo un `WHERE Cuenta = '100-1000'`

Comment: tal vez como `where Cuenta  like   '000%'`

Comment: En el UPDATE a la tabla RESUMEN; Al momento en que obtienes la suma de los montos podrías poner lo siguiente:  "Select SUM(Monto) FROM TABLA where Fecha = Fecha1 AND Clasificacion = Clasificacion AND Cuenta = '201-0000'"

Comment: Genial ya aplique y si funciona solo que los que son diferente de `Cuenta like '000%'`. u otro valor me los traer en 0

Comment: actualice la pregunta por el detalle del where

Comment: He modificado la respuesta. La condición el like colocarlo en Insert select a la tabla @RESUMEN

Comment: Muchas gracias , enserio muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puesto que ya hay una solución, pero es poco eficiente, creo que debo dejar una alternativa más sencilla y rápida.

La lógica de fechas la tuve que imaginar de acuerdo a los parámetros mostrados, pero el concepto se puede aplicar de distintas formas y solo hace falta cambiar la condición de cada columna y agregar condiciones generales en el WHERE que apliquen a toda la consulta.

```
--Generar datos de prueba
DECLARE  @TABLA AS TABLE
(
    Cuenta        VARCHAR(50), 
    Nombre        VARCHAR(100), 
    Monto         FLOAT, 
    Fecha         DATETIME, 
    Clasificacion VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO @TABLA
(
       Cuenta, 
       Nombre, 
       Monto, 
       Fecha, 
       Clasificacion
)
VALUES 
    ('201-0000','ACREEDORES DIVERSOS','1206047.85','20180106', 'Acreedores Diversos'),
    ('201-0000','ACREEDORES DIVERSOS','25633.85'  ,'20190105', 'Acreedores Diversos'),
    ('201-0000','BANCO ACTINVER'     ,'9919.29'   ,'20180106', 'Acreedores Diversos Sub'),
    ('201-0201','BREVO SEMINUEVOS'   ,'0'         ,'20180106', 'Acreedores Diversos Sub'),
    ('201-0201','Nombre 1'           ,'8500.35'   ,'20190105', 'ACTIVO'),
    ('201-0201','Nombre 2'           ,'10500.45'  ,'20190105', 'PTU'),
    ('201-0201','Nombre 3'           ,'10500.45'  ,'20190103', 'Otros Ingresos');

--Necesario si el servidor no está configurado correctamente
SET LANGUAGE 'Spanish'

--Parámetros mostrados en el procedimiento
DECLARE 
       @Periodo1        VARCHAR(10)  = '[ene#-18]', 
       @Periodo2        VARCHAR(10)  = '[ene#-19]';

--Variables para manejar los parámetros como fechas
DECLARE @Fecha1 datetime,
        @Fecha2 datetime;

--Convertir los parámetros a fechas de inicio de mes
SELECT @Fecha1 = TRY_CAST( REPLACE( '01-' + REPLACE( PARSENAME(@Periodo1, 1), '#', ''), '-', '/') AS datetime),
       @Fecha2 = TRY_CAST( REPLACE( '01-' + REPLACE( PARSENAME(@Periodo2, 1), '#', ''), '-', '/') AS datetime)

--Mostrar los montos en dos columnas de fechas.
SELECT Clasificacion,
    SUM( CASE WHEN Fecha >= @Fecha1 AND Fecha < DATEADD( MONTH, 1, @Fecha1) THEN Monto ELSE 0 END) AS Fecha1,
    SUM( CASE WHEN Fecha >= @Fecha2 AND Fecha < DATEADD( MONTH, 1, @Fecha2) THEN Monto ELSE 0 END) AS Fecha2
FROM @TABLA
GROUP BY Clasificacion;
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias @Luis Cazares , tambien adapte tu respuesta a mi problema y tambien lo soluciona , Muchas Gracias por tomarte tu tiempo , Saludos, si pudiera marcaba las 2 respuestas como respuestas validas